# Case sensitive abbrev expansion

Tags: emacs, elisp

Why is abbrev-mode limited to lower-case abbreviations only?

```
(define-abbrev-table 'c++-mode-abbrev-table
  '(
    ("8g" "struct" nil 0)
    ("8G" "class" nil 0)))
```

Here, `8G` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works for me.  What makes you think it doesn't _seem_ to work?  Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the reply. I tried it with `emacs -Q` and it worked. the cause was `subword-mode`, I hope it gets fixed before 25.1

Comment: Unlikely it will ever get fixed if you don't `M-x report-emacs-bug`.